# How to show Javascript confirm box when checkbox is unchecked and then if user selects cancel, leave the checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a small `html form` with three checkboxes, one in each `row`. I want to have a `javascript confirm box` show when the user unchecks the box, and then if the user selects cancel, the `checkbox` remains checked. I've searched this site and a few others but almost everything was to do with the `checkbox` being checked, like if they had to agree to some terms or something. I am very new to `Javascript` however I tried to make a function based on what I though it should look like, but it doesn't work.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox One</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this.name)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Two</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this.name)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Three</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this.name)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And here is the function I tried, but doesn't work:

```
function cTrig(name) {
  if (name.checked == true) {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbENV/1/)

I would prefer something in `Javascript` as I want to become more familiar with that language before getting into `jquery`, but if it has to be done in `jquery`, then that is fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This Way

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox One</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="check1" id="check1" checked='checked' onchange="cTrig('check1')"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Two</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" checked='checked' onchange="cTrig('check2')"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Three</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check3" checked='checked' onchange="cTrig('check3')"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

*By Using Element Id*

```
function cTrig(clickedid) { 
      if (document.getElementById(clickedid).checked == true) {
        return false;
      } else {
       var box= confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
        if (box==true)
            return true;
        else
           document.getElementById(clickedid).checked = true;

      }
    }
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RbENV/8/)

*By Using Name*

```
function cTrig(clickedid) { 
      if (document.getElementsByName(clickedid)[0].checked == true) {
        return false;
      } else {
       var box= confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
        if (box==true)
            return true;
        else
           document.getElementsByName(clickedid)[0].checked = true;

      }
    }
```

[Demo Using element name](http://jsfiddle.net/RbENV/11/)

Comment: **Checkboxes** should assign `id` property.

Comment: @NewDeveloper yeah i had that in demo link, anyway i have posted the code here...thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This is PERFECT! Thank you very much! I wish I could give +2 for your thoroughness and for giving two different answers, BOTH using Javascript as requested. Thank you Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

I would do it this way:

Your form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox One</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Two</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox Three</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" checked="checked" onchange="cTrig(this)"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
function cTrig(box) {
  if (!box.checked) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?")) {
        box.checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I modify this so that a div is shown with confirmation buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Uses jQuery (because it's just better) but I could whip it up without if needed:

```
$('#check1').change(function(){
    if($("#check1").prop('checked') == false)
    {
        var i = window.confirm("Sure?");
        if(i == true)
        {
            $("#check1").prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#check1").prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

This additionally assumes you're assigning each checkbox an id, which you will need to. Name doesn't cut it in this case.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" checked="checked"></input>
```

etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/RbENV/10/

Note that I went the native way for the confirm dialogue, but using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) you can control the box alot more.

EDIT: Added a check to make sure it only happens when you're unchecking it. Missed that part. (Note you check for false because when the change event fires the change has already happened)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Although it works very well, I chose @Sibu answer because it was in Javascript.