# How can I use Javascript to keep the total of checkboxes selected and display it?

Tags: javascript, html

This snippet of code doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.

```
<html><body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" onclick="updateTotal('a',5)">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" onclick="updateTotal('b',3)">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" onclick="updateTotal('c',4)">3<br>
TOTAL: &pound;
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;
    function updateTotal(row, val){
            global total;
            if (document.getElementByID(row_no).checked){
                total += price;
            }
            else {
                total -= price;
            }
            document.write(+total);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it work the way I want? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `price` is not defined and `global total` is invalid. This is javascript not php.

Comment: I hope this will be helpful for you: [How to deal with checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208022/how-to-show-javascript-confirm-box-when-checkbox-is-unchecked-and-then-if-user-s)

Answer (score 2):

It is full of JS errors... you can check it here: http://www.jslint.com/

If you want it to work, you could try something like that:

```js
var total = 0;
updateTotal = function (row, val){
    if (document.getElementById(row).checked){
        total += val;
    }
    else {
        total -= val;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML ="TOTAL: "+ total +"&pound;";
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a" onclick="updateTotal('a',5)">5<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b" onclick="updateTotal('b',3)">4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c" onclick="updateTotal('c',4)">3<br>
    <span id="total">TOTAL: &pound;</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented your solution. I knew my code was full of little tiny errors and that it would take me a while to find them all. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

checke this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/5rxu1as5/7/)

```
var total = 0;
function updateTotal(row, val){
    if (document.getElementById(row).checked){
        total += val;
    }
    else {
        total -= val;
    }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues. Please take a look at this fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d15m4uLu/)

```
var total = 0;
function updateTotal(row, val) {
    if (document.getElementById(row).checked) {
        total += val;
    } else {
        total -= val;
    }
    console.log(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things need changing from your example. First you pass val into the function but use price. I have replaced price with val.

In javascript you don't need to use

```
global total;
```

total will already be accessible inside the function.

getElementById uses camel case and javascript is case sensitive so the last character need to be lower case. You also need to give the checkboxes an ID not just a name.

If you update the innerHTML inside a tag rather than document.write it will update the value rather than writing one value after another. 
You also have too many close brackets.

```
<html><body>
<script>
    var total = 0;
    function updateTotal(row, val){
            if (document.getElementById(row).checked){
                total += val;
            }
            else {
                total -= val;
            }
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total;
        }

</script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" onChange="updateTotal('a',5)">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" onChange="updateTotal('b',3)">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" id="c" onChange="updateTotal('c',4)">3<br>
TOTAL: &pound; <x id="price">0</x>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```